# Enable javax.validation.constraints in arangodb-spring-data

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, arangodb

There is any way to enable **javax.validation.constraints** (like @NOTNULL annotation in the model) using **arangodb-spring-data**?

For example in **mongodb-spring-data** you must add a Configuration Class likes:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
    return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
  }
  @Bean
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
  } 
}
```

I tried simply using the annotations without any configuration but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no thing like `ValidatingMongoEventListener` in Spring Data ArangoDB. You must validate entities yourself before saving them to the DB.

**UPDATE:**

You can validate your objects like this:

Use `javax.validation.Valid` annotation on a controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/myobjects")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> saveMyObject(@Valid @RequestBody MyObject obj) {
    repo.save(obj);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

Or do it manually:

```
@Autowired
private javax.validation.Validator validator;

public void saveMyObject(MyObject obj) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyObject>> violations = validator.validate(obj);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
         throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
    repo.save(obj);
}
```

Comment: Do you suggest to define custom annotation Constraint using the javax.validation.ConstraintValidator or maybe exists a quicker way to implement it?

Comment: You want to validate your objects before you save them to the DB? If so, it depends on your use case. Are your objects provided by a user via a controller method?

Comment: Yes, I need to validate them before they have been saved and they are provided by users via a controller. Thank you for your response I will try it.